# Generating unique 3 character city code through c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have to generate a 3 character city code like '001' to '999'. After that it should be 'a01' to 'a99', then 'b01' to 'b99' and so on. How to generate it through the c# code and insert it into city table. I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Sorry I meant cities

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. The site doesn't work as a free source for code, you need to provide your code, which has a problem, or doesn't work as expected. See [ask].

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? What's wrong with using an int identity column in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build with linq

```
var list = (from number in Enumerable.Range(1, 99) select string.Format("{0:000}", number)) // 1 - 999
                .Union (from number in Enumerable.Range(1, 26 * 100) where number % 100 != 0 select string.Format("{0}{1:00}", (char)(97 + number / 100), number % 100)); // ?01 - ?99 where ? is a to z
```

But be minded, the city code your are using is meaningless to human, you should really decide another coding scheme for use.

Comment: I got it, using enumerables is a better option. Also i will consider your opinion.